# Erlang: Foldl function parameters swapped

Tags: erlang, foldleft

Why is the accumulator `AccIn` not the left parameter for `Fun` ? 
http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#foldl-3

```
foldl(Fun, Acc0, List) -> Acc1


Fun = fun((Elem :: T, AccIn) -> AccOut)
Acc0 = Acc1 = AccIn = AccOut = term()
List = [T]
T = term()
```

I ask this because nearly every other functional language (e.g. `haskell`, `scala`) has it the the other way round. You're meant to visualize a left fold as accumulating from the left as

`foldl f z [x1, x2, ..] = ((z f x1) f x2) ..`

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as in Haskell:

> foldl(Fun, Acc0, List) -> Acc1
>
> foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a

Comment: No. I think you missed the spec for erlang's foldl. Try comparing that with the haskell-version.

Comment: What you've copied is the haskell spec. `(a -> b -> a)` has `a` as the same type as the accumulator. Now compare that to erlang's which is more of the kind `(b -> a -> a)` and you'd get what i'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Consistency of argument order between the different versions of folds was simply considered more important than any such algebraic visualization as you mention.